# Load before start async storage in React Native - useEffect

Tags: react-native, file, react-hooks, load, asyncstorage

I have this code in my app that will render a FlatList based in a information from a json file. I added a DropDown to be able to change the data, It's working but too late, I need to load the information before the app starts.

Code:

```
const data = require('../../utils/examData');
var index = 0;
var questions = data[index].Questions;

export function Home(): JSX.Element {

  if(isLoaded == false){
    useEffect(() => {
        (async()=>{
             await getData()
        })();
        }, [])
    isLoaded = true;
  }  

  async function getData() {
    var result = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Config', (err, result) => {
      if(result) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(result);
        index = obj.lastFile;
      }
    });

    if(result) {
      var obj = JSON.parse(result);
      index = obj.lastFile;
    }
    questions = data[index].Questions;
  };

  let [currentCard, setCurrentCard] = useState(0);
  cardListRef = useRef<FlatList>(null);  
  
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
  const [items, setItems] = useState(data.map((examData, index) => ({ label: examData.FileName, value: index })));

  async function changeExam(value) {

    const config = {
      lastFile: value 
    };

    AsyncStorage.setItem(
      'Config',
      JSON.stringify(config)
    );

    Updates.reloadAsync();
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     
      <DropDownPicker
        onSelectItem={(item) => {
          changeExam(item.value);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I don't know how to make it load the `getData()` method first of all

Edit.:  I tried to add it right after declaring the index variable at the very beginning of the code outside the `Home()` function, but then I get this error 'Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.'

Comment: Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: @VasylNahuliak Even if I remove the IF it still loads very late, needed to load first of all, I tried to add it right after declaring the index variable at the very beginning of the code outside the Home() function, but then I get this error 'Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.'

Comment: You need Thinking in React https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html Do not use variables outside the component if you want to change them. You need use `useState` for all changes data